# Terraform authentication multi-subscription using multiple service principals

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-managed-identity, terraform-cloud

I want my terraform scripts to be able to authenticate on multiple azure subscriptions using multiple service principal.

Here is what I think:

- Create a service principal (App registration).
- Deploy terraform scripts in azure container instances
- Give the "*contributor*" role to my service principal on the subscription (x)
- Configure terraform scripts with environment variables to select the right credentials when I want to create resources in this subscription.

> ```
> $ export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=159f2485-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx     # Client subscription
> $ export ARM_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx           # client_id of the service principal
> $ export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
> $ export ARM_TENANT_ID=72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx           # the same tenant for all clients
> ```

Is this correct?

Do you have a more secure way to authenticate on multiple subscriptions when using terraform cloud? (ideally without client_secret)

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the container instance can run Terraform script, then there is no problem with the steps. You give permission to the service principal and change the environment variable `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` for different subscriptions, then Terraform script works for different subscriptions.

A safer way is to use the [authentication with Azure CLI](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/azure_cli). If you set different subscriptions with the CLI command:

```
az account set --subscription="SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
```

Then the Terraform script will also work for different subscriptions. In this way you don't need to set the secret as the environment variable.

Comment: This command will be executed inside terraform container (in my Azure subscription), but the TF scripts will be executed on Terraform Cloud, so I think that the server which will run TF will necessarily ask the client_secret to authenticate on the different subscriptions

Comment: @admin Do you see the variable I provide in the answer? You can use multiple providers with different subscription id. Try it.

Comment: @admin Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just waiting for the creation of the second subscription to test it.
I let you know as soon as possible.